# searching elastic search filtering results with and and or conditions

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with the following documents:

```
{
    "first_name": "f1",
    "last_name": "l1",
    "location": "SF",
    "vehicle": {
        "type": "car",
        "color": "red"
    }
}


{
    "first_name": "f2",
    "last_name": "l2",
    "location": "SF",
    "vehicle": {
        "type": "motorcycle",
        "color": "blue"
    }
}

{
    "first_name": "f3",
    "last_name": "l3",
    "location": "SF",
    "vehicle": {
        "type": "bicycle",
        "color": "green"
    }
}

{
    "first_name": "f4",
    "last_name": "l4",
    "location": "CA",
    "vehicle": {
        "type": "motorcycle",
        "color": "green"
    }
}

{
    "first_name": "f5",
    "last_name": "l5",
    "location": "SF"
}
```

The **vehicle** document is a nested type.

I would like to filter results:

> SELECT WHERE location=SF AND (vehicle.type=car OR
>   vehicle.type=airplane OR not-exists(vehicle.type)

I could not find a way to do it.

Is there a way to execute such a filter on Elasticsearch?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it, it is a bit complex but:

```
GET indextests/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "location": "SF"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "vehicle",
                  "query": {
                    "terms": {
                      "vehicle.type": ["car", "bicycle"]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "vehicle",
                        "query": {
                          "bool": {
                            "should": [
                              {
                                "bool": {
                                  "must": [
                                    {
                                      "exists": {
                                        "field": "vehicle.type"
                                      }
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This query might be helpful.

```
POST IndexName/Type/_search
{
  "query": {
  "bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "term": {
        "location": {
          "value": "sf"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "terms": {
              "vehicle.type": [
                "car",
                "airplane"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "bool": {
              "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "vehicle.type"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
}
```

If you want to search location by case sensitive then use below query. I have used `location.keyword` for match case sensitive.

```
POST IndexName/Type/_search
{
  "query": {
  "bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "term": {
        "location.keyword": {
          "value": "SF"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "terms": {
              "vehicle.type": [
                "car",
                "airplane"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "bool": {
              "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "vehicle.type"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to use filter since I don't care about the scoring and it should be faster, no? I am trying this and will update. Thanks

Comment: I checked that, it seems to be working, however I am wondering, the vehicle object is a nested object, why don't you add a nested part with the path? how come it is working this way?

Comment: I have to go back with my previous comment, I tried, but it is not working. I think it is related to the fact that the vehicle object is a nested object. I tried by removing the part of terms(vehicle types) and just trying to search location=SF and not exists part, but still I am getting documents with vehicle.type

Comment: As per your question, Below three scenarios happened
1) location = 'SF' and vehicle.type = 'car'
2) location = 'SF' and vehicle.type = 'airplane'
3) location = 'SF' and vehicle.type field does not exist,

If anyone from aforementioned 3 conditions will be satisfied, it will return the result.